# If $a\mid b$ then $\phi(a)\mid \phi(b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: divisibility, integers, prime-factorization, totient-function

Hey I would like to show that

> $a\mid b\Rightarrow \varphi(a)\mid\varphi(b)\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

where $\varphi(n)$ is the the *totient* function.

My try:

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\mid b$. By Eulers formula we have that
$$
\varphi(a)=a\cdot \prod_{\substack{p \mid a\\ p\ \text{prime}}} \Big(1-\frac{1}{p}\Big).
$$
Now since $a\mid b$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic we can factorise $a$ and $b$ into
$$
a=\prod_{i=1}^{n} p_i^{\alpha_i} \qquad b=\prod_{i=1}^{m} p_i^{\beta_i}
$$
with $p_i$ being primes, $n \le m$, and $\alpha_i \le \beta_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Using this we can say 
$$
\left.\prod_{i=1}^{n} \Big(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\Big) \middle| \prod_{i=1}^{n}\Big(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\Big)\right.
$$
and this concludes the result.

Now my question is that is this correct? If it is is there another way to arrive to this conclusion? My way of describing this felt a bit clucky.

Happy new years eve to all!

Comment: Compare your solution with the answer of Xucheng Zhang at the duplicate.

Comment: Nice thank you. How do you find duplicates so fast?